# finding a not-so-straightforward game's function

Tags: binary-analysis, functions, function-hooking, game-hacking, virtual-functions

I am working on Mad Max game [ APEX engine ]
I do my best to explain the situation.

so my target executes function like this:
there are commands like " call [eax+XX] " or " call RX " and these execute all functions.
I was able to find some functions by referenced string but this particular function, I just can't, any name I guess ends up wrong.

I want to unlock upgrades. I tried Cheat Engine's Ultimap and found nothing ( except the saving function which saves when a different addon/upgrade is selected ). it seems the checking function is run constantly maybe with different arguments.

so as the calling routine is like this I cant trace back. it's so confusing. there was another game by this engine ( Just Cause 4 ) where I could trace back a string like " X is locked" and reach the deciding code but this one is just driving me crazy.

I think the game uses Vtable but can't find it (i think even if I do, I need leaked SDK and symbols to recognize functions) I tried the IDA pro 7.5+ plugins with no luck.

there are also strings like " bla-bla\bla-bla\XXX_unlock_condition.gsr" and i don't know if they are packed within exe (denuvo protected) or packed within .arc and .tab files. and if it's possible to dump them.

Comment: It sure is allowed to name your RCE target.

Comment: @0xC0000022L thanks

Comment: But what is the question? If it's called like [eax+XX] then there is high probability that it's virtual function, and no, you don't need symbols to push this work further. It's all about your RE skills

Comment: @morsisko well, the question here is i need some help as i lack the experience you are referring to. every tool i use is not working to get the Vtable.